# Columns with replicated duplicates in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, datatable, duplicates

I am a noob to R and I have a data set that is similar to this:

```
   room1   MLT   153
   room1   GMV   188
   room1   TWV   258
   room2   MLT   585
   room2   GMV   698
   room2   TWV   400
   room3   MLT   888
   room3   GMV   481
   room4   MLT   081
```

The first column is replicated duplicates of room1, room2 ect. Column 2 has the corresponding replicates.
I want the data like this:

```
       MLT GMV TWV
room1  153 188 258
room2  585 698 400
room3  888 481 NA
room4  081 NA  NA
```

Note: I don't want to use this data. I want a formula in general in R for changing replicated duplicates together to recreate the data frame. Thanks.

I'm guessing this is a pretty frequent question. I haven't found videos or questions for this simple mundane question anywhere on the internet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format

Comment: df %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = Room, names_from = Col1, values_from = Col2) where Room, Col1 and Col2 are column names